# Not able to boot vmdk file in vmware exported from google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, vmware, vmware-workstation

I wanted to test vmdk files exported from google cloud with my vmware workstation 16 pro, however it doesn't seem to work, a cursor just blinks on the screen and there is no progress after that.

- To export a vmdk file from Google cloud, I followed below steps:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image

- And to boot from vmdk in vmware workstation, following steps were referred.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010196

Please help to get this resolved.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-A438B4FE-8499-454C-BBDE-9299FCDFB455.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a disk fragment issue while exporting a vmdk file. Hence it didn't work in vmware. I created a fresh vm instance in gcp and did an export, then it worked.